# How to select date in jquery datepicker based on another jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker1").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date });
            });
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker2").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date });
            });


        </script>
```

if i select `date(example: 12-08-2013)` in `#datepicker1`, i need to select date in `#datepicker2` on or after `date(example: 12-08-2013).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        maxDate: new Date,
        onSelect: function(date){
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
        }
    })
});
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        maxDate: new Date
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TewrW/)